# Rollback transaction after commit in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Can I rollback record after successfully saved?

Lets I have a user model with attribute name,email and so on.

For ex.

```
u=User.new
u.name="test_name"
u.email="test@email.com"
u.save
```

Now record will be successfully saved in database after that I want to rollback my transaction (not destroy or delete). Have any idea?

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with transactions, see http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/

Example:

```
User.transaction do
  User.create(:username => 'Nemu')
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run console in sandbox mode

```
$> rails c --sandbox
```

- On exit all changes rollback to the point of enter.

Answer (score 3):

There's also a gem called PaperTrail that we've been using with great success.  It might do a little more than you want.

> PaperTrail lets you track changes to your models' data. It's good for
>   auditing or versioning. You can see how a model looked at any stage in
>   its lifecycle, revert it to any version, and even undelete it after
>   it's been destroyed.

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

No affiliation.